# parse json data with gson on android

Tags: android, gson

My model looks like this:

```
public class DefaultModel<T> {
    public int Status;
    public T JSON;
    public String ErrorMessage;
    public String InfoMessage;
}
```

The json font style

```
{"ErrorMessage":"null","InfoMessage":"null","JSON":
[{"DictId":"1","ItemCode":"1","ItemName":"sINGLE","SortNum":0,"
isChecked":true},{"ItemName":"WenJackp","SortNum":0,"isChecked":false}]
,"Status":100}
```

I want parse this json, but gson throws exception

> com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to
>   xxxxx.DictItem

How to parse ?

---

add more details, I use this method parse json data:

- create ParameterizedType and you see buildType method

  ```
  ParameterizedType mType = buildType(DefaultModel.class, ArrayList.class, DictItem.class);
  ```
- parse json data

  ```
  DefaultModel<List<DictItem>> mResult = mGson.fromJson(json, mType);
  ```
- create new ParameterizedType

  ```
  protected ParameterizedType buildType(final Class raw, final Type... args) {
      return new ParameterizedType() {
          public Type getRawType() {
              return raw;
          }

          public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
              return args;
          }

          public Type getOwnerType() {
              return null;
          }
      };
  }
  ```

The above is when I deal with JSON parsing method used by the, I want use `Default<List<DictItem>>` this type , `T == List<DictItem>`

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/serializing-and-deserializing-json-from.html

Answer (score 1):

For type 'T' use

```
List<InnerClass> json;
```

Then you can put an inner class into your DefaultModel that would have

```
String dictId;
String itemCode;
String itemName;
String sortNum;
boolean isChecked;
```

On a side note these variables should be marked private and accessed via a getter.
You can also have different variable names if you wish by annotating them with @SerializedName

eg

```
@SerializedName("ErrorMessage")
private String myErrowMsg;
```

Comment: Thank you answer my question ! You may not know my description of the problem,Later I added more description of the problem